# Как сделать ProgressBar и Timer?

Tags: delphi

Как сделать в Delphi так, чтобы постепенно, в течение времени `progressBar position` увеличивался?

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, `progressbar position` увеличивался, к примеру, на 5%? То есть для того, чтобы прогресс бар position была равна 100, нужно 20 нажатий на кнопку.

Comment: См. <a href="http://hashcode.ru/questions/46798/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2-progressbar">тут</a>, там достаточно инфы.

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример работы ProgressBar по таймеру:

```
procedure TForm3.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ProgressBar1.Position:=ProgressBar1.Position+1;
  If (ProgressBar1.Position=ProgressBar1.Max) Then
    Timer1.Enabled:=False;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Двигать `ProgressBar` можно и без применения выражения `Position := Position + 1`.
Просто используйте метод `StepIt`

```
Form.ProgressBar.StepIt;
```

По умолчанию свойство `Step` равно 1.
Менять можно так:

```
Form.ProgressBar.Step:= 5;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Постепенно со временем:
    Нужен 1 timer.
   Ставил нужный интервал времени:
       Timer1.Interval:= 1000; // 1000 = 1 секунда (10000 - 10 сек).

Даубл клик по таймеру (при его срабатывании):

```
ProgressBar1.Position:= ProgressBar1.Position + 5; // каждую секунду (1000) - увеличивается на 5.
```

1. При нажатии на Button:

ProgressBar1.Position:= ProgressBar1.Position + 5; // 20 нажатий - и вот Вам 100 %

Т.е. тоже самое,что и с таймером.